# Como puedo actualizar mi version de PHP sin usar Homebrew en macOS big sur

Tags: php

Alguien me podria ayudar con el problema que tengo, al intentar actualizar php con homebrew me sale lo siguiente:

[image: Error brew postinstall php]

luego de eso hago link con brew link php y al utilizar el comando php -v me sale lo siguiente: [image: Illegal instruction]

Answer (score 1):

Borra la carpeta e instalalo de cero

```
sudo rm -r /usr/local/Cellar/php
brew update
brew upgrade
brew install php
```

Comment: No me funciono, me sigue saliendo el mismo error, alguna otra solución?

Comment: que error te da?

Comment: El mismo que sale en la segunda captura, Illegal hardware instruction

Comment: lo estas haciendo en pasos? cuando ejecutas esto que te tira? brew install php